# Java android EventBus get two this same events

Tags: java, android, greenrobot-eventbus

I create event I send this event on free activities. But When I send on only one Activity I have in 
@Subscribe method called multiple time for the same event

Comment: Could you check there are other functions expecting same parameter on the parent class of your activity. Additionally, question is not clear, maybe code piece is needed to make it more understandable.

Comment: @Erdem only in one activity I have a function expecting this parameter